# Substract dates from previous row

Tags: sql-server-2008

I couldn't see any question matching this one so I made this question.

I have this result from my code and the last thing I need is to substract the dates so I get the real dates:

| EmployeeId |  From date   | Till date        | AbsenceID | DenseRank |
|     M1266     | 2015-03-01 |  2015-03-22 |          4        |         2          |
|     M1266     | 2015-03-15 |  2015-03-22 |         14       |         1          |

I want the till date for AbsenceID 4 to be 2015-03-14 as the person can't have both absences at the same time in this situation.

The problem is that one of the tables don't update as the employee makes a change in the bookings so that I have to calculate it manually.

code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    EmployeeID, FromDate, TillDate, AbsenceId, DN2
FROM(--B
SELECT 
    *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeID, TillDate ORDER BY FromDate DESC) DN2
FROM(--A
    SELECT --DISTINCT
        LogTrans.EmployeeID, LogAbs.FromDate, LogAbs.TillDate, LogAbs.AbsenceID, LogAbs.KeyNo, LogAbs.LNo, LogTrans.LNo 
    FROM 
        LogTrans, LogAbs
    WHERE 
        LogAbs.AbsenceID > 0 AND 
        EmployeeID = 'R000000000001266' AND
        CONVERT(varchar(10),FromDate,20) >= '2015-02-28' and
        CONVERT(varchar(10),TillDate,20) <= '2015-03-23' AND
        ((
        LogTrans.LNo  = LogAbs.LNo AND 
        CONVERT(varchar(10),LogTrans.DateAndTime,20) >= CONVERT(varchar(10),FromDate,20) and
        CONVERT(varchar(10),DateAndTime,20) <= CONVERT(varchar(10),TillDate,20)
        ) OR
        (
        LogTrans.KeyNo= LogAbs.KeyNo AND 
        CONVERT(varchar(10),DateAndTime,20) >= CONVERT(varchar(10),FromDate,20) and
        CONVERT(varchar(10),DateAndTime,20) <= CONVERT(varchar(10),TillDate,20)
        ))
)A
)B
ORDER BY FromDate, TillDate
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @tSample TABLE
(   EmployeeID VARCHAR(50)
,FromDate DATE
,TillDate DATE
,AbsenceID INT
,DenseRank INT)

 INSERT INTO @tSample (EmployeeID,FromDate,TillDate,AbsenceID,DenseRank)
 VALUES ('M1266','2015-03-01','2015-03-22',4,2)
,('M1266','2015-03-15','2015-03-22',14,1);

SELECT 
A.EmployeeID
,A.FromDate
,ISNULL(DATEADD(DAY,-1,N.FromDate),A.TillDate) AS TillDate
,A.AbsenceID
,A.DenseRank
FROM
   @tSample AS A
   OUTER APPLY
   (SELECT TOP(1)
        B.FromDate
    FROM @tSample B
    WHERE A.EmployeeID = B.EmployeeID
    AND B.FromDate>A.FromDate
    ORDER BY B.FromDate ASC
  )N;
```

the output:

```
EmployeeID  FromDate    TillDate    AbsenceID   DenseRank
M1266       2015-03-01  2015-03-14  4           2
M1266       2015-03-15  2015-03-22  14          1
```